# Hydra with Weblogic for testing credentials

Tags: weblogic, brute-force, hydra

I'm looking for the good syntax with Hydra in order to validate the good credentials. My local weblogic server is running on 192.168.100.21, so far I've tried the following:

```
hydra -C userpass.txt -M my-local-IP.txt -o results.txt http-get -s 7001 -f -q -t 2 -m /console/j_security_check

hydra -C userpass.txt -M my-local-IP.txt -o results.txt http-head -s 7001 -f -q -t 2 -m /console/j_security_check

hydra -C userpass.txt -M my-local-IP.txt -o results.txt http-post-form "/console/j_security_check:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:F=failed" -s 7001 -f -q -t 2
```

So far none of them have been printing in the output 'results.txt' the valid credential.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to test against the WebLogic admin console. Here's a working example for a WebLogic 11g/12c installation.

```
hydra 192.168.100.21 -s 7001 -l <username> -p <password> http-post-form -m "/console/j_security_check:j_username=^USER^&j_password=^PASS^:Authentication Denied"
```